# Can Oracle dmp files be ingested into Snowflake with COPY INTO command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Just wanted to check if its possible to ingest Oracle dmp files directly into Snowflake via COPY INTO command.
We are able to ingest gz(gzipped) and bz2 files but not sure if Snowflake support Oracle dmp files.
Would appreciate if someone can help

Answer (score 0):

GZIP and BZ2 are supported compression formats (see documentation below and associated link).  There are also file formats that are supported.  Depending on your dump file, it should meet those requirements and may be unsupported if using a different compression algorithm or file format:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-prepare.html#data-file-compression

If it's not loading successfully, I might recommend pre-processing the file into a supported format listed here. Oracle may even have some tools or utilities to convert/export dump files.